# Split untill end of line powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a script in PowerShell which adds a hyphen after every each 2 characters which is in a text file, and i have done it but I am facing an issue which is.

**Code >**

```
$file = get-content .\textfile.txt
($file -split "([a-z0-9]{2})"  | ?{ $_.length -ne 0 }) -join "-" | Set-Content .\textfile.txt
```

If i have a value like below in a `.txt` file

```
000000000000

111111111111
```

Output is coming like.

```
00-00-00-00-00-00-11-11-11-11-11-11
```

I need an output like.

```
00-00-00-00-00-00

11-11-11-11-11-11
```

Kindly suggest what should i have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on the TechNet Forums at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e60e33d2-f065-4219-82cf-5797aaf10891/split-foreach-line?forum=winserverpowershell

This will add a dash (-) after every two characters in a line. Since it will also do this at the end of a line, we trim it.

```
$inputFile = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\file.txt

$newFile = foreach ($line in $inputFile) {
   ($line -replace '(..)', '$1-').trim('-')
} 

$newFile | Set-Content -Path C:\temp\file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` removes all the newlines, and outputs strings to the pipeline, one for each line.

`$file` is an array of two strings, `@('000000000000', '111111111111')`. When you `-split` it applies to both of the strings, and it turns into `@('00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11', '11')` and now you cannot tell where the lines start or end.

To fix it, you need to process each line separately:

```
(Get-Content .\textfile.txt) | ForEach-object { 

    ($_ -split "([a-z0-9]{2})" |? { $_ }) -join "-" 

} | Set-Content .\textfile.txt
```

Or change what you're doing to do a replace, that will work within the lines instead of merging them together:

```
(gc .\textfile.txt) -replace '([a-z0-9]{2})\B', '$1-' | sc textfile.txt
```

and the `\B` stops it from putting a `-` at the end of the line.